# How to log everything into a log file using logger Python

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to duplicate everything that could display on console to a log file. This includes unhandled exceptions and test results from unittest.

Curranty following is not being done,

1. unhandled exceptions is NOT being logged into the log file.
2. test results from unittest is NOT being logged into the log file.

#2 is more important for me.

I work in Lunux/Unix but it would be great if the solution will work on Windows as well.

Any help will be appreciated. Below is my code,

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logfile = datetime.now().strftime(pathlib.PurePath(__file__).stem + '_%H_%M_%d_%m_%Y')

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    logFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
    rootLogger = logging.getLogger()
    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("{0}.log".format(logfile))
    fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
    rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler)
    rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
    consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
    rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

def test_logging(self):
    self.fail("Why is this not being logged into the log file?")
```

Comment: is the missing closing quote on line 2 just a cut and paste error?

Comment: Yes, just copy paste error. Still unable to get everything duplicated on screen and in log